# Clipboard management GUI with ability to save images to file

Tags: software-recommendation, clipboard

Is there a clipboard management GUI where I can view the images in the clipboard and choose to save any of them to a file, all without using the command line?

I know how to save copied images to file using the command line (`xclip -selection clipboard -t image/png -o > mypic.png`), but I'm looking for a pure GUI solution. I tried copyq but it does not have any option of saving images through its GUI.

I am using a random mix of desktop environments, so I require a desktop environment-agnostic solution.

Comment: Save images to file in CopyQ: https://github.com/hluk/CopyQ/issues/252